# Adobe PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

When i rebuild my app, i have an error: ":mergeReleaseResources FAILED".

Could you help me to resolve it?

I think it's due to splash.png file but it doesn't exist...

See below a part of log file with error

```
:mergeReleaseResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 1183437625) : No Delegate set : lost message:libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.
> Crunching Cruncher splash.png failed, see logs
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 1.562 secs
Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
AAPT err(Facade for 1183437625) : No Delegate set : lost message:libpng error: Not a PNG file
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.
> Crunching Cruncher splash.png failed, see logs
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Comment: had you tried after putting the file in it ?

Comment: I do not have that file

Comment: create the same named file of some  png image . try that

Comment: where putting this file

Comment: In www folder of your application.

Comment: i tried this but i always have the same error

Comment: Nobody have another suggession?

Answer (score 0):

open all your resource images with paint and re "Save As" them to png.

you probably see that one or more images will not try to "Save As" as png directly but as bmp or jpg, they are the corrupted images! Save them all to PNG!

Something went wrong previously you saved them as jpeg inside the data file but they are called with file extension as png.

It worked for me. See ya.